# How to add current time as default in time picker?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here is the how I try to get date picker and add the current time as default

.HTML

```
    <input type="time" [(ngModel)]="time">
```

.TS

```
      time;

      constructor() {
    
        this.time= new Date();
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your question for current time the following works for me.

Html code:

```
<input id="MyCurrentTime" type="time">
```

typeScript code:

```
timeNow=new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(" ")[0];

document.getElementById("MyCurrentTime").setAttribute("value",this.timeNow);
```

Works this way as well.

HTML Code

```
<input id="MyCurrentTime" type="time"  [(ngModel)]="timeNow">
```

Typescript code:

```
timeNow=new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: Hi the above code works for me. Please let me know if it works for you as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
this.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

Because these fields are typed (date, time, datetime) their initialization is not new Date(), is literally what they ask: Date: "yyyy-MM-dd" and Time: "hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

If you can use moment js library, try doing:

```
  this.time = moment().format('LTS'); // 11:21:21 PM
   //OR
 this.time =moment().format('LT'); // 11:21 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to tell the time you can use HTML to create a button and make a button that tells the time.

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```